# Grails Export Plugin - File not found browser error

Tags: grails-plugin, export-to-csv

I'm trying to use the `Grails Export Plugin` for exporting a result set as `CSV`. I got this export method on my custom scaffolding controller template:

```
def export() {
    response.contentType = "text/csv"
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${className}.csv")
    exportService.export("csv", response.outputStream, ${className}.list(params), [:], [:])
}
```

The problem is that when I hit this action I get a `File not found` error from browser. What am I doing wrong? Is this supposed to force a file download?

Comment: What is className ? Where are you defining it ? Try explicitly mentioning the className(domain) and the filename.

Comment: This is in the scaffold controller template, so ${className} value is the name of the domain class associated with the current controller. I also tried hardcoding a certain domain class name and got the same error.

Comment: I tested your approach the same way and its working for me, the only thing I made change was on export tag I mentioned the action name `<export:formats action="export"/>` and make sure you have `def exportService` on your controller class template

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Alidad. I'm not using the taglib for generating the export link, just hitting manually an url like /user/export. Is there maybe something I need to add to the url? Format param is hardcoded on export action, so I'm not sure what's happening here...it's really weird... I have def exportService in my controller template.

Comment: Try it with tag once to see if that's the reason, the only thing I can think of is you are not hitting the right action or you are using ajax call to get to that action.